# Problem rendering the contents of array using map on reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I use `axios` to get the data from the server and store the received data into the array `setCountries`. This part works.

[Code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-monad-g5p09?file=/src/App.js)

Then, I simply want to render the whole list of country names contained on the array using map.
I am making some  mistake there, because I get the error

> TypeError: setCountries.map is not a function

The error comes from this part of the code.
Where is the error coming from?

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])

const showCountries = () => {
 
  return (
    <div>
    <ul>
      {setCountries.map((country) => 
          <p key={country.alpha2Code}>{country.name}</p>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}



  return (
<div>

<div>
<h1>Countries</h1>

{showCountries()}
</div>

</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using function **`setCountries`** instead of array **`countries`**

Corrected:

```
 <ul>
    {countries.length > 0 && countries.map((country) => 
      <p key={country.alpha2Code}>{country.name}</p>
    )}
  </ul>
```

> Also use null checks to avoid other issues

Answer (score 0):

`setCountries` is a function for setting the `country`'s state. It does not have the `map` function.
The solution here will be to use `countries.map` instead:

```
const showCountries = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {countries.map((country) =>
        <p key={country.alpha2Code}>{country.name}</p>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setCountries is a function and that's why you can't use a map. If you try the code I wrote below, your problem will be resolved.

```
{countries.map((country) => 
          <p key={country.alpha2Code}>{country.name}</p>
        )}
```